# I would like to change the text in <div> tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How can I change the text in a `<div>` tag dynamically according to audio? I have the text of an audio file and have the time when that text will come in the audio. At a particular time, the text should change.

I am trying to do it with the following code, but the text is not displaying in the `<div>` tag.

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
  media.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    if(position > 0){
      // position is current position of audio which is playing
      if(position < 2.40) {
        console.log("Lets sit comfortably easily");
        $scope.profile.text = "Lets sit comfortably easily";
      } else {
        $scope.profile.text = "Lets close our eyes";
      }
    }
  }, function(error){
    console.log(error);
  })
}, 1000);
```

The console is printing, but the text is not displaying in the `<div>` tag.

Please share your ideas on why it is happening.

Comment: please add your html

Comment: you should add an angularjs tag to your question

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `$scope.$apply()`.

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
media.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
if(position > 0){
  // position is current position of audio which is playing
  if(position < 2.40) {
    console.log("Lets sit comfortably easily");
    $scope.profile.text = "Lets sit comfortably easily";
  } else {
    $scope.profile.text = "Lets close our eyes";
  }
  $scope.apply();
}
}, function(error){
console.log(error);
})
}, 1000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `$interval`. It will take care of `$apply` internally

Comment: to call $scope.apply(); from a timer it is not a better particle, as a convenience, AngularJS provides $timeout and $interval which is like setTimeout and setInterval.

Comment: Obviously we must use $interval instead setInterval, but I was trying to solve the problem of setInterval function without $interval.

Answer (score 0):

do not use setinterval,
you must user $interval angular function.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

setinterval is outside the angular context then for each timer tick your interface in not updated.

$interval will internally call $apply function for each timer tick, automatically updating your view.

Comment: Adding reason would help OP understand why... because it internally will call `$apply()` and setInterval() is outside angular context

Comment: you do not call apply() for each timer tick, i do not see it in your code.

Comment: pleased to help you

Comment: I am not the one who asked question...I was adding comment to suggest explaining why use `$interval` for a more complete answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113480/discussion-between-danilo-calzetta-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score -3):

$("#myDivId").text("My new text.");

Comment: No jQuery in stack OP is using

Comment: Why jQuery and not AngularJS?

Comment: Not original enough for a downvote.  Why repeat what the guy in front of you said?